# user.identity.getuserid() return user id value in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have an issue on sign out process as after sign out user.identity.getuserid() returns the userid value, whether it should return null.
Here is my code,

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Logout()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I have checked in 'Immediate Window' after sign out it return user id value.

Comment: Could that be a 'caching' issue, related to the current web request? If you call `Logout` a second time (straight after) what is the value of `userId` on that second request?

Comment: I have attached screenshot. Please click on Screenshot here

Comment: I cleared cache but result is same.

Comment: The identity is stored in a cookie and sent to the server in the http request. Sign out tells the browser to expire/ delete the cookie. However you’ve set the breakpoint before sending back the response to the browser. Next request should have User as null

Comment: Have a look at my second question Asif (about a second call to Logout). What is the answer to it?

Comment: I checked in second request user was null.Thanks all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signout Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138882/signout-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity is stored in a cookie and sent to the server in the http request. Sign out tells the browser to expire/ delete the cookie. However you’ve set the breakpoint before sending back the response to the browser. Next request should have User as null