# Signout Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a signout on my APP like this :

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

The problem is that when I return to my Login Activity and I press again Sign in it does a re-login with the same account.

What I'd like to do is something like this :

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApliClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                statusTextView.setText("Signed out");
            }
        });
```

If I do this (it's a button from Login Activity) it lets me log in with different account, but if I do only the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` it does sign out, but if I do Login it re-log with the old email, is there any way to do this without having to create the `mGoogleApiClient`, etc..? I have to do this in differents Activities and I don't want to create it on each Activity, if I do it works I've tested it, but I think it's kinda dirty.

Comment: I don't know of an alternative to calling `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut()`.  If you truly need sign-in/sign-out capability in multiple activities, you could put the GoogleApiClient connect processing in a base class to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and I solved it doing this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        this.finishAffinity();
    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext,LoginActivity.class));
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

**`finishAffinity()`**

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.